# How to implement SWF exponential retries using the aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I'm trying to implement a jruby SWF activity worker using AWS SDK v2.

I cannot use the aws-flow-ruby framework since it's not compatible with jruby(forking), so I wrote a worker that uses threading.

https://github.com/djpate/jflow if people are interested.

Anyway, in the framework they implement retries and It seems that it actually schedules the same activity later if an activity failed.

I found everywhere in the AWS docs and cannot find how to send that signal back to SWF using the SDK http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SWF/Client.html

Anyone know where I should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, I believe you are somewhat confused about what SWF is / how it works.

Activities don't run and are not retried in isolation. Everything happens in the context of a workflow. The workflow definition tell you when to retry and how to behave if activities fail/timeout etc.

The worker that processes the workflow definition and schedules the next thing that needs to happen is referred to as a decider. (you will see decider and workflow used interchangeably). It's called a decider because based on the current state it makes the decision on what the next activity that needs to be scheduled is. The decider normally takes the workflow history as input when making this input.

In Flow for example, the retry is encoded in the workflow logic. Basically if the activity fails you can just schedule it.

So to finally answer your question: if your target is to only implement the activity workers you don't need to implement any retry logic as that happens at the decider level. You should make sure that the activities are compatible with the decider (you need to make sure the history and the input/output convention are the same). 
If your target is to implement your own framework on top of SWF you need to actually do the hard work needed to make the decider work.